# Xamarin Studio how to write namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, xamarin.ios

In C# is normal to write namespace

`namespace ProjectName.Folder` so if project is `Test` and then folder name inside project is `Utils` then namespace is

```
namespace Test.Utils
```

In Xamarin projects in Github namespace is always the same so just

```
namespace Test
```

so what is now better to use, always the same namespace or like in Visual studio?

Comment: Its a matter of preference, but that being said, code organization for your APIs should take a front stage. If it should be logically separated into different namespaces, do it. I'm guessing the GitHub examples you were looking at were just that, examples to demonstrate some feature, not hard rules about organizing code and namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly personal preference.  Xamarin Studio by default uses a single namespace per project, which is probably why most examples you see are written that way.  There is an option you can change to make it behave more like Visual Studio

> Preferences --> Source Code --> .NET Naming Policies --> "Associate
>   namespaces with directory names"